# How compare/cast SQL rowversion field data in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have two records in my student table with a row-version field. I am creating the object of that record as student class in my C# code.

My question are:

1. In which C# compatible datatype is rowversion data cast?
2. How do I compare rowversion of two records and find which one is the latest in C#?

Answer (score 15):

One way to find the latest rowversion is to use the [`StructuralComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.structuralcomparisons.structuralcomparer.aspx)

```
var r1 = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00};
var r2 = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0xFF};

bool r1_is_newer = StructuralComparisons.StructuralComparer.Compare(r1, r2) > 0;
```

A benefit of the structural comparisons is that they automatically deal with `NULL`s

Regarding use of the `BitConverter`. If the above byte arrays were converted to `UInt64` using the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx) , you'd end up with very high numbers and the comparison is meaningless (as the rowversion changes by one, the uint64 converted number changes by around 2^56)

If you'd like to sprinkle some LINQ over it to make it extra slow, you can use

```
bool r1_is_newer = 
  Enumerable.Zip(r1, r2, (b1, b2) => new { b1, b2 })
  .SkipWhile(item => item.b1 == item.b2)
  .Take(1).Any(item => item.b1 > item.b2);
```

Comment: What does the `> 0` do in this case?

Comment: The `Compare` function returns a signed integer that indicates the relative values of r1 and r2:
- If less than 0, r1 is less than r2.
- If 0, r1 equals r2.
- If _greater than 0_, r1 is greater than r2 ... indicating that r1 is newer

Answer (score 3):

`rowversion` is `binary(8)`, and will be returned as a `byte[]` if you use `SqlCommand`/`SqlDataReader`.  If you use EF 4.1, the corresponding property will also be `byte[]`.

You could use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) to convert to `UInt64` and then compare.  You could also return the rowversion cast as `bigint` from SQL Server, which would appear as a `long` in C#.  In either case, the larger value would have been created later.

In my own tests, I've seen that rowversion starts at a small, positive value (not 0).  If you do cast to `bigint`, you'll have to consider what will happen when it reaches `2^64`.  In my case, it's not something I have to worry about.  If you think that will happen in your database, then you'll have to add logic to handle that in your comparison, or just stick with `BitConverter.ToUInt64`.

Also, be careful if your `rowversion` column accepts `NULL`; You'll have to account for that if it does.

Comment: Using `BitConverter` is a bad idea because of little endian byte ordering. It's OK if you compare for equality only. However, when checking which one is latest, then you will not get correct results